# Daily Datapoints plotted with Plotly Lineplot - Smoothing the data

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

This is the Data ranging from 12-08-2020 until 22-04-2022, with Datapoints for every day.
[image: Data]

This is how my Plot currently looks:
[image: Current Plot]

What I now would really like, is that it would just plot the average of the whole line. But I can't seem to find anything. I tried using the keyword `line_shape=spline` but it didn't make it look better.
I currently use this:
`fig = px.line(x=count_by_day['creation_date'], y=count_by_day['count'], line_shape='spline')`

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it my using the 7 day rolling average

```
count_by_day['count'] = count_by_day['count'].rolling(window=7).mean()
```

Looks exactly how I wanted it:
[image]